# Python function to extract specific values from complex JSON logs data

Tags: python, json, data-structures, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a Python function (for use in a Google Cloud Function) that extracts specific values from JSON logs data. Ordinarily, I do this using the standard method of sorting through keys:

```
my_data['key1'], etc.
```

This JSON data, however is quite different, since it appears to have the data I need as lists inside of dictionaries. Here is a sample of the logs data:

```js
{
  "insertId": "-mgv16adfcja",
  "logName": "projects/my_project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "email@email.com"
    },
    "authorizationInfo": [{
        "granted": true,
        "permission": "resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy",
        "resource": "projects/my_project",
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "name": "projects/my_project",
          "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
          "type": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project"
        }
      },
      {
        "granted": true,
        "permission": "resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy",
        "resource": "projects/my_project",
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "name": "projects/my_project",
          "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
          "type": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project"
        }
      }
    ],
    "methodName": "SetIamPolicy",
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.SetIamPolicyRequest",
      "policy": {
        "bindings": [{
              "members": [
                "serviceAccount:my-test- 
                sa @my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com "
              ],
              "role": "projects/my_project/roles/PubBuckets"
            },
            {
              "members": [
                "serviceAccount:my-test-sa- 
                2 @my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com "
              ],
              "role": "roles/owner"
            },
            {
              "members": [
                "serviceAccount:my-test-sa-3@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                "serviceAccount:my-test-sa-4@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
              ]
            }
```

My goal with this data is to extract the "role":"roles/editor" and the associated "members." So in this case, I would like to extract service accounts my-test-sa-3, 4, and 5, and print them.

When the JSON enters my cloud function I do the following:

```
pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
msg = json.loads(pubsub_message)
print(msg)
```

And I can get to other data that I need, e.g., project id-

```
proj_id = msg['resource']['labels']['project_id']
```

But I cannot get into the lists within the dictionaries effectively. The deepest I can currently get is to the 'bindings' key.

I have additionally tried restructuring and flattening output as a list:

```py
    policy_request =credentials.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=proj_id, body={})
    policy_response = policy_request.execute()
    my_bindings = policy_response['bindings']
    flat_list = []
    for element in my_bindings:
        if type(element) is list:
            for item in element:
                flat_list.append(item)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    print('Here is flat_list: ', flat_list)

I then use an if statement to search the list, which returns nothing. I can't use indices, because the output will change consistently, so I need a solution that can extract the values by a key, value approach if at all possible. 

Expected Output:
Role: roles/editor
Members:
sa-1@gcloud.com
sa2@gcloud.com
sa3@gcloud.com
and so on
Appreciate any help.
```

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question

Comment: The indentation of your JSON is strange, and has unbalanced braces. Can you correct?

Comment: *"msg['resource']['labels']['project_id']"*: there is no "labels" key anywhere in your data, nor "project_id". We cannot help when you are referencing things that are not in your input.

Comment: In your code block you use `policy_response` but never define that. We cannot help if you reference variables of which the definition is missing.

Comment: Added expected output, tidied the JSON and updated with where I instantiate policy_response. Thanks again!